# How to do a Closest Facility Analysis using OSM?

Tags: openstreetmap, network, closest-facility, graphhopper

I have  locations of about 1100 Branches across the country, and I want to find the closest branch for any user-provided point.

I'm looking at OSM data, and supporting tools to do this, since I don't have access to ArcGIS Network Analysis. I was planning to set up an instance of a tool like GraphHopper or something similar.

I looked at the tools mentioned [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing), and none of them mention *Closest Facility solving*.

Is there any tool which does closest Facility on OSM data, or am I going to have to calculate the distances from Multiple facilities to my input find, to find the closest tool?

Comment: You can calculate the distance and/or time from the user input to these locations and pick the shortest using a local GraphHopper server or faster via the GraphHopper Matrix API (note, I'm one of the founders)

Comment: @Karussell: Thanks for the great product that you have developed. Can the Matrix API be run on a local/docker instance of GraphHopper?

Comment: The matrix API is not open source https://www.graphhopper.com/open-source/ and for details about our product please reach out to us via Email.

Comment: But it is important to note that the open source solution can handle this as well but will be slower (in your case just a bit depending on the implementation)